# how to generate pdf and save to server

Tags: php, pdf

Well, i'm trying to generate pdf file and save it to server but when i'm trying to view that pdf its showing invalid format.

Code :

```
<?php
$content = "32w434";
file_put_contents("xyz.pdf",$content);
?>
```

If i change file from pdf to doc it works and opening perfectly but not pdf

```
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$content = $pdf->Output();
file_put_contents("xyz.pdf",$content);
```

That code giving output i don't want output on browser and still file is corrupted / invalid format

Comment: That's because it doesn't save it as a PHP file. That's just text. Examine te file in a text editor next to a PDF in a text editor

Comment: i'm not opening from ftp i'm directly opening it from link and also after downloading from cpanel

Comment: It's not that it's corrupt download. Find out more on the PDF file format and instead use fpdf

Comment: I have the same question, is complicated but is possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$content = $pdf->Output('doc.pdf','F');
```

http://www.fpdf.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can use FPDF to generate pdf file....

```
http://www.fpdf.org/
```

This is simple and best way to generate pdf...

Comment: i try it but their documentation is too big i just want my html to be converted in pdf

Comment: hey this is efficient way to create pdf file. You have to mention the co-ordinates only. if you try this u can do it in 30 mins. One question, whether data is dynamic or constant one?

Answer (score 1):

Use TCPDF to generate PDF file,

TCPDF Site: http://www.tcpdf.org/

Demo: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Answer (score 0):

@Mohit,

This

```
$content = $pdf->Output('doc.pdf','F');
```

generates a new file.  If your file is generated using variables that can change in php, the pdf file you see on screen, will be different from the pdf file saved on the server.

Answer (score -1):

You should generate pdf file using pdf libraries such as tcpdf or fpdf. Putting contents directly into a file with .pdf extension will definitely not working since pdf has its own file format